# После обновления PHP до 7.3, не запускается Laravel. Как исправить?

Tags: php, laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini` директиву `shor_open_tags` исправил на `On`.
Не помогло. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: Nginx/Apache настроили на новую версию PHP? Меняется версия - меняется название сокета...

Comment: делал по мануалу https://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/. Завелось с первого раза

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar как произвести данную настройку?

Comment: @ArchDemon ничего не поменялось

Comment: В настройках для PHP-FPM проставьте ваш PHPшный  сокет с учетом новой версии, как вам уже порекомендовал @VladimirGonchar (https://ruhighload.com/Конфигурация+nginx+%2B+php+7). Также учтите что CLI файл конфигурации, в котором вы меняли - это для запуска из PHP из консоли, а не через NGINX. Вам нужна директория fpm, а не CLI. В общем, читайте про то как настраивать версии и конфигурацию для своей связки.